# How to "pair" two widgets side by side in one sidebar

Tags: widgets, sidebar

Currently I use the Pinboard theme with 2 sidebars. In each sidebar I place one kind of widget several times. The point is that 2 widgets of a row (1 of each sidebar) belong together regarding the content.

What I really want is that I could place the 2 different widgets (belonging together) side by side in one sidebar and repeat this for the others in the same sidebar. I found the extensible widgets plugin (http://wordpress.org/plugins/extensible-widgets/) but it isn't maintained anymore for 3 years. So I didn't install it. Furthermore, I found some discussions about solving similar problems with tables or with css anyhow.

For better understanding you can see my WP instance here: http://turbine.reimone.net/

My problem is that each widget in a "widget pair" must be configured. 
The first widget is an event widget which comes from the All-in-One Event Calendar by Timely plugin and the second widget just is a text widget containing simple html. A "widget pair" is meant to be 2 widgets belonging together by content. Both widgets of a pair should be aligned side by side in the layout. I hope that both upper edges (one of each widget) in a pair are on the same vertical level so that visitors can determine better which widgets belong together.

Can you help me to solve this?

Comment: Please work on formatting this question-- line break, paragraphs, basic stuff. What do you mean by "pair" the widgets? Are you talking about formatting-- ie. side by side? Or are you talking about settings?

Comment: Sorry for that. It was my first question here. I updated my post.

Comment: Is creating one sidebar an option? You could then output corresponding divs float:left; within their own div.

Comment: If I understand the 2 widget in a pair are in 2 different sidebar. I think only chance to align them vertically is use a js function that run once on document ready and on every window resize. That is a dirty solution at all. Best solution in your case is create one sidebar with two columns (in this case the widget pair will take both colums) or create a widget with 2 tabs.

Comment: Yeah I would structure it like I mentioned... Made a basic fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WebEnvelopment/yNqVz/

Comment: Where's your code? What have you done so far to try and code this? You could do this simply using CSS like float: left and float: right or using Bootstrap column classes.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your site, it appears you have six pairs of widgets that need to be displayed side by side and aligned at the top. There are two ways I can see of fixing this:

1. Using the current layout, use CSS to add top margins to each of the rightmost column's widgets to line them up with the existing widgets on first column. This is a quick fix, but will require separate `margin-top` declarations for each widget in that column and will likely  be wonky when the site is viewed in different browsers and/or display sizes.
2. Update your theme to have six separate widget areas on your sidebar (see the [WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes)) and put a pair in each. Then updating your CSS to float the individual widgets side by side. This will likely be a better and more flexible long-term solution.